# asp.net mvc razor view - redirect based on the value of a form control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, anchor

I have the following anchor tag in MVC 5 razor view:

```
<a href='@string.Format("https://www.abc.ac.fj/index.php?id=10820&Full_Name={0}&Email_Address=@Model.EmailContact", name)' target="_blank">Pay Now</a>
```

and a form control for the `EmailContact` property

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailContact)
```

The email address, I am trying to use from the Model property but it's not working. When you click this link, the value that gets rendered is "@Model.EmailContact" but not it's actual value.

Please assist.

Comment: Use `&Email_Address={1}", name, Model.EmailContact)`

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke...When I do that, it gives me: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the line prior to this line...I tried putting the entire <a> tag inside @{...} but still same error...Please guide

Comment: It means your model is `null`!

Comment: Thanks Stephen...I did this to test and what you advised is correct.            @if (Model != null)
                            <a href='@string.Format("https://www.abc.ac.fj/index.php?id=10820&Full_Name={0}&Email_Address={1}", name,Model.EmailContact)' target="_blank">Pay Now</a>
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="https://www.bbc.com">BBC</a>
                        }    but the problem I have is my this page is a GET page and not a POST page so the user fills the email contact on this very page.

Comment: This email contact I am filling into the Model.EmailContact property. Initially the model value is null so how can I use the value that the user fills on this page to pass onto that <a> tag. Many thanks.

Comment: Your using razor code which is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. If you want to create a link based on the value of a form control, then you need to use javascript/jquery to build the url.

Comment: Many thanks @StephenMuecke...I will use javascript to do that...How do I accept your answer...I cannot see any option to Accept your answer...by the way my Reputation score is 11...Is it because of that?

Comment: Its because I have not added an answer :) - and I wont unless you edit your question to explain what your actually doing - i.e. you need to redirect based on the value of a form control

Comment: I have edited the question....:)

Comment: Okay thanks and noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You format the `href` value, you would need to use

```
<a href='@string.Format("https://www.abc.ac.fj/index.php?id=10820&Full_Name={0}&Email_Address={1}", name, Model.EmailContact)' target="_blank">Pay Now</a>
```

however `@string.Format()` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its passed to the view, so it will be the initial value of `EmailContact` and does not take into account a value edited in the textbox.

You need to build the url using javascript/jquery. Change the link to

```
<a id="pay" href="#" data-baseurl='@string.Format("https://www.abc.ac.fj/index.php?id=10820&Full_Name={0}", name)'>Pay Now</a>
```

and add the following script

```
$('#pay').click(function() {
    var baseUrl = $(this).data('baseurl');
    var url = baseUrl + '&Email_Address=' + $('#EmailContact').val();
    window.open(url, '_blank')
});
```